# OS X will not update past 10.11

Tags: macos, software-update

I am currently enrolled in the public beta for OS X.

I have OS X El Capitan 10.11 beta (15A278b). When I sent my feedback through the Feedback Assistant, I could not even select this build in the dropdown (I could only choose between 15E65 and 15F18c).

I have not received any updates to the later versions of OS X. App Store currently has no updates for my machine (everything is apparently up to date).

I thought about opting out of the public beta, but the option does not appear in System Preference > App Store (the section with the "Change" button is missing).

I downloaded OS X 10.11.4 from Apple's web site, but it tells me "OS X El Capitan Update can't be installed on this disk. This volume does not meet the requirements for this update."

I did not find someone else with the same issue. I want to avoid having to restore my Mac.

I'm on a 15-inch Retina MacBook Pro (late 2013).

Comment: Are you able to download the El Capitan installer from the App Store?

Comment: I did not think of this. From what I see, the only one available in the "Purchased" tab is "OS X El Capitan GM Candidate." I've gone ahead and started downloading it. I'll comment when it is done.

Comment: Issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had the GM version installed. I downloaded the standard OS X from the App Store, installed it, and everything is fine now.

Comment: I will. Ask Different is telling me to wait for tomorrow.